# Using zmq_recv and ZMQ_NOBLOCK versus zmq_poll for one socket

Tags: network-programming, zeromq, nonblocking

There seem to be two main ways to asynchronously get data from your socket in ZeroMQ:

```
if(zmq_recv(&msg, ZMQ_NOBLOCK) == 0) { // could return EAGAIN or others
    // do stuff
}

...and...

if(zmq_poll(&pollItems[0], num, timeout)) {
    if(zmq_poll(&msg) == 0) {
        // do stuff
    }
}
```

If I only have one socket that I want to read from, is there a compelling reason I should opt for the version that uses `zmq_poll` rather than `zmq_recv` with `ZMQ_NOBLOCK`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would rarely do a `zmq_recv(&msg, ZMQ_NOBLOCK)` without using `zmq_poll`

Normally you would read in a loop;

```
while (!done) {
...
  zmq_recv(&msg, ZMQ_NOBLOCK);
... 
}
```

This is a busy wait, it uses CPU unnecessarily. `zmq_poll()` blocks, and don't consume CPU while it's waiting for something to happen.

If you only have one socket, and don't want to use zmq_poll, you would normally use a blocking `zmq_recv`, and set a ZMQ_RCVTIMEO so you don't block forever if something has gone bad at the sending side.